# Mocking Sitecore Database using Sitecore FakeDb

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sitecore

I'm currently unit testing some methods that calls sitecore database. The class has an attribute of Sitecore Database and uses that to get the items. I'm thinking of using Sitecore FakeDb to mock the items. Is there a way that I can use Sitecore FakeDb to test the methods?

```
public class myClass
{
    private Database myDb;

    public string getMyItemValue()
    {
        var myItem = myDb.GetItem(SomeID);
        string myItemValue = myItem["value"];

        return myItemValue;
    }
}
```

I also created a constructor for the class

```
public myClass(myDatabase)
{
    myDb = myDatabase;
}
```

Now on the unit test I'm trying to use Sitecore FakeDB. I've tried using the basic FakeDb information that I got from this link https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb. The code breaks when passing the FakeDb parameter to the class since it is not a Database. I'm using Xunit by the way.

```
public class myClassTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void myItemValueTest()
    {
        using (var db = new Db
        {
          new DbItem("myItem") { { "value", "hello world!" } }
        }){
            myClass myclass = myClass(db); /*code breaks here*/

            string myItemValue = myclass.getMyItemValue();
            Assert.Equal("hello world!", myItemValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should distinguish Sitecore `Database` and FakeDb `Db` classes. In the production assemblies, you definitely need the first one (and only the first one). The FakeDb `Db` class is needed for unit testing purposes only.

Prior to Sitecore 8.2 the `Sitecore.Data.Database` class was static and it wasn't possible to mock it in unit tests. The `using new Db()` statement allows to configure the *in-memory* data provider in a way that allows you to use the standard Sitecore API to create and retrieve the test content. You should always keep in mind that there are two kind of API.

In your sample, the Sitecore database can be reached via `db.Database` property:

```
var database = db.Database;
myClass myclass = myClass(database);
```

Starting from Sitecore 8.2, the static `Database` class has been split into abstract `Database` and concrete `DefaultDatabase` classes. That enables database mocking *without* FakeDb.